# Is Son Hak a Dragon?

Tags: yona-of-the-dawn

Is Son Hak from the anime/manga *Akatsuki no Yona* a dragon? I'm thinking he is because he's so overpowered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is Son Hak a Dragon?** No, he is not. He is just someone powerful. It is clearly stated in [here](http://akatsukinoyona.wikia.com/wiki/Hak#Abilities):

> *Although not a dragon blood*, he matches the strength of other dragons easily.